# Linq to SQL duplicating entry when referencing FK

Tags: silverlight, linq-to-sql

I am still facing some problems when using LINQ-to-SQL.
I am also looking for answers by myself, but this problem is so akward that I am having problems to find the right keywords to look for it.

I have this code here:

```
public CustomTask SaveTask(string token, CustomTask task)
    {
        TrackingDataContext dataConext = new TrackingDataContext();

        //Check the token for security
        if (SessionTokenBase.Instance.ExistsToken(Convert.ToInt32(token)) == null) return null;

        //Populates the Task - the "real" Linq to SQL object            
        Task t = new Task();
        t.Title = task.Title;
        t.Description = task.Description;

//****The next 4 lines are important****
        if (task.Severity != null)
            t.Severity = task.Severity;
        else
            t.SeverityID = task.SeverityID;

        t.StateID = task.StateID;

        if (task.TeamMember != null)
            t.TeamMember = task.TeamMember;
        else
            t.ReporterID = task.ReporterID;

        if (task.ReporterTeam != null)
            t.Team = task.ReporterTeam;
        else
            t.ReporterTeamID = task.ReporterTeamID;

        //Saves/Updates the task
        dataConext.Tasks.InsertOnSubmit(t);
        dataConext.SubmitChanges();

        task.ID = t.ID;

        return task;
    }
```

The problem is that I am sending the the severity, and then, when I get this situation:

DB State before calling the method:

ID      Name
1       high
2       medium
3       low

Call the method selecting "medium" as severity

DB State after calling the method:
ID      Name
1       high
2       medium
3       low
4       medium

The point is:
-Why is it duplicating this entry??

Some explanation about the code:
CustomTask is almost the same as Task, but I was having problems regarding serialization as can be seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4536011/error-when-sending-an-linq-to-sql-object-to-the-server-using-wcf)

Edit: just found out that the code is sending an Severity object and not the ID, I am going to change it. But it is still very strange that it duplicates the entry :(

Edit2: Updated the question due to new information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problems was that the services are Rest, so a new DataContext is created every call, generating the duplicated entry.
Using the ID avoids this problem.